# Quickly find the min and max coordinates of connected component in a large image

Tags: python, image, performance, numpy, matrix

I have an image that is of size `50000x50000`. It has around `25000` connected different connected components. I'm using `ndimage.label` to label each of them and then I find the non zero points and finally get the min x, max x, min y and max y values. However, I have to find these coordinates is for each of the `25000` connected components. This is expensive as I have to run `np.nonzero` on the `50000x50000` image `25000` times. Here is a snippet of the code doing what I just mentioned.

```
im, _ = ndimage.label(im)
num_instances = np.max(np.max(im))
for instance_id in range(1,num_instances+1):
    im_inst = im == instance_id 
    points = np.nonzero(im_inst) # running this is expensive as im is 50000x50000

    cropped_min_x_1 = np.min(points[0])
    cropped_min_y_1 = np.min(points[1]) 
    cropped_max_x_1 = np.max(points[0])+1 
    cropped_max_y_1 = np.max(points[1])+1
```

Does anyone know what I can do to significantly speed up this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fraction of labelled pixels is not too large:

```
nz = np.flatnonzero(im)
order = np.argsort(im.ravel()[nz])
nz = nz[order]
blocks = np.searchsorted(im.ravel()[nz], np.arange(2, num_instances+1))
# or (which is faster will depend on numbers)
blocks = 1 + np.where(np.diff(im.ravel()[nz]))[0]
coords = np.array(np.unravel_index(nz, (50000, 50000)))
groups = np.split(coords, blocks, axis=-1)
```

groups will be a list of 2xn_i coordinates where n_i is the size of component i.

Comment: Wouldn't we want to produce a 4xn_i array since there are 4 coordinates, min x, min y, max x, max y?

Comment: It's the coordinates of all the points of that segment. I left extracting the min/max as an excercise ;-) I just see that's a bit confusingly phrased. each element of the output list is an 2xn_i array. There is an element for each segment i

Comment: Ah, so in your code we should replace `im` with `im_inst` right? And `groups` is more or less just `points` in my code?

Comment: No, the trick is to do the nonzero only once, so it should definitely be on `im`. That means we start with a big mess of all segments mixed together, so do an indirect sort and then nsplit where the segment index changes. As we did this indirectly, i.e. using indices it remains to translate these flat indices back to coordinates and that's more or less it. It should be more efficient than doing nonzero 25,000x . Memory could be a problem, though. How much do you have? Can't be too little since you can store 50,000x50,000 pixel images.

Comment: May I ask you how you came up with this? My first question, did you decide to use `np.flatnonzero()` so it would be easier to manipulate with other numpy functions. That way we don't have to deal with the axis? I have a hunch that this is a neat trick that could be useful for all sorts of problems.

Comment: In principle one could use 2d indices for the indirect sort etc, but as you suspect it is less hassle with just one indexing array and I guess also faster because numpy needn't translate the 2d indices into linear memory offsets. And yes, it is also true in this case that for the grouping by id the 2d structure is more of a distraction than easily exploitable. How I came up with this? I think it's mostly experience. Sorting if there is nothing cheaper is certainly a recurrent theme. I don't know what else I can tell you.