# Efficiently creating masks - Numpy /Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy array with shape (50, 10000, 10000) with 1000 distinct "clusters". For example, there would be small volume somewhere with just 1s, another small volume with 2s, etc. I would like to iterate through each cluster to create a mask like so:

```
for i in np.unique(arr)[1:]:
    mask = arr == i
    #do other stuff with mask
```

Creating each mask takes about 15 seconds, and iterating through 1000 clusters would take more than 4 hours. Is there a possible way to speed up the code or is this the best there is since there is no avoiding iterating through each element of the array?

EDIT: the dtype of the array is uint16

Comment: You have a 5GB numpy array?

Comment: How do you plan to use those masks? Because pre-computing all masks would result in a huge mask array, so don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  Sorry. Should mention that the dtype is uint16, so not really 5GB.

Comment: @Divakar the mask is used to calculate volumetric centroid of each cluster.

Comment: Stick to the loopy version for such a huge data.

Comment: Is it really creating the mask or rather the call to np.unique that takes that long?

Comment: Anyway, here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42499219/7207392) to a similar Q, that might work for you. It doesn't create masks but rather coordinate lists but depending on your problem that may be ok I suppose.

Comment: Where is this array coming from?  For example, if it's the `.labels_` array of `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`, you can also call `.cluster_centers_` without having to do any of this calculation.

Comment: Also, is `arr` sparse?  Since you say your volumes are small, but your array is huge, it makes me wonder if there's a lot of elements of `arr` that aren't assigned to a cluster (i.e. have value `0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `arr` is sparse:

- you say the clusters are small, and 1000 clusters isn't going to tile an array that big
- you iterate over `np.unique(arr)[1:]`, so I assume the first unique value is `0`

In this case I would recommend leveraging a [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
sp_arr = csr_matrix(arr.reshape(1,-1))
```

This turns your big dense array into a one-row compressed sparse row array. Since sparse arrays don't like more than 2 dimensions, this tricks it into using ravelled indices.  Now `sp_arr` has `data` (the cluster labels), `indices` (the ravelled indices), and `indptr` (which is trivial here since we only have one row).  So,

```
for i in np.unique(sp_arr.data):  # as a bonus this `unique` call should be faster too
    x, y, z = np.unravel_index(sp_arr.indices[sp_arr.data == i], arr.shape)
```

Should much more efficiently give equivalent coordinates to

```
for i in np.unique(arr)[:1]:
    x, y, z = np.nonzero(arr == i)
```

where `x, y, z` are the indices of the `True` values in `mask`.  From there you can either reconstruct `mask` or work off the indices (recommended).

You could also do this purely with `numpy`, and still have a boolean mask at the end, but a bit less memory efficient:

```
all_mask = arr != 0    # points assigned to any cluster
data = arr[all_mask]   # all cluster labels
for i in np.unique(data):
    mask = all_mask.copy()
    mask[mask] = data == i  # now mask is same as before
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the answer. Working with indices is much faster than recreating masks. Are there some resources out there where I can learn more about leveraging numpy/scipy?

Comment: That resource is pretty much the online documentation, and StackOverflow.  Try searching questions or just browse the post history of Divakar, MSiefert, COLDSPEED,etc.